# Remove Rows that meet a certain numerical criteria in Pandas (Python 3)

Tags: python, pandas

Right now, my code exports a CSV that looks like this

```
 Keyword        Sum          Score     Observances
  Green           0           inf          1 
  Eggs            5            3           2
  And            10            5           3
  Ham             0           inf          4
```

**What I would like to do** is to remove all those rows that contain a 0 within the Sum Column and contain "inf" under score.

my code right now goes as follows:

```
newlist = df1.join(s)
def func(x):
    return pd.Series({'Observances': len(x),'Sum': x.Conv.sum(),'Zero': len(x[x.Conv==0])})
group = newlist.groupby(['Keyword']).apply(func).reset_index()
score = group.Sum / (group.Observances - group.Zero) 
group['Score'] = score
```

I've tried to replace all of the "inf" with NaN and then use the Pandas function to remove them but that didn't seem to work (may have done it wrong).  I've read the .filter function may be what I'm looking for but still not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry you want to remove all rows that have less than 5 in sum OR have inf in Score?

Comment: How does the code you provide relate to the question?

Comment: ha! just figured it out almost right after I posted that, appreciate the responses and interest however.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code I provided above, this answer was a simple as using the following code to remove anything equal to 0:

```
removal = group[group.Sum != 0]
```

Or the following code to remove anything less than 5:

```
removal = group[group['Sum'] >= 5]
```

This solved my problem because the "inf" were dependent on the 0 in the sum column -- by removing one I got rid of both